# Select day or month from a timestamp and assign into a variable

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, timestamp

I have a table with hundreds of rows and I want to assgin the day of the first row in a variable, also a month in other variable.
The column is a timestamp format.

Right now I have a stored procedure like this, but I think it doesn't work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AUTO_FLTER_BY_DATE IS
startDay number;
startMonth number;
endDay number;
endMonth number;
BEGIN
    SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM tstamp) INTO startDay FROM "SYSTEM"."TEST_DATES";
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(startDay);
END AUTO_FLTER_BY_DATE;
```

And this is an example of the timestamp column

```
01-FEB-20 01.30.05.024000000 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following

```
to_char(tstamp, 'DAY')

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AUTO_FLTER_BY_DATE IS
startDay number;
startMonth number;
endDay number;
endMonth number;
BEGIN
    SELECT to_char(tstamp, 'DAY') INTO startDay FROM "SYSTEM"."TEST_DATES";
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(startDay);
END AUTO_FLTER_BY_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
create or replace procedure auto_flter_by_date
as
    startDay number;
    startMonth number;
begin
    select extract(day from min(tstamp)) as startday
         , extract(month from min(tstamp)) as startmonth
    into   startDay, startMonth
    from   test_dates;
    
    dbms_output.put_line('First day: '||startDay);
    dbms_output.put_line('First Month: '||startMonth);
end;
```

I advise not touching the SYSTEM schema, or using double-quotes.